# How to document a webpage HTML and CSS using comments

Tags: html, css, documentation, comments

Are there any standards for developing a documentation of a HTML and CSS file for other developers to be able to understand using comments and the structure of the code?

Comment: Hope this helps: https://www.drupal.org/node/1887862 and this: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html

Comment: Nice, they are well detailed, thanks @Hardy

Comment: And what about the documentation of the whole webpage or template in a word document? How do you go about that just in case clients ask for it?

Comment: np, doxygen is best program for auto-generating documentation from source code if the source is just commented right way.. check it out: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/index.html

Comment: Let me try it and I will give you feedback on the results.

Comment: Doxygen on supports Php which I have, is there another for HTML5 and CSS?

Comment: I don't think there is need for document HTML or CSS in that level.. the basic comments are enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things you can do to make your code more understandable for other developers. What I would rank as the most important thing is to indent your code properly.

The code structure is paramount for understanding the different elements used. HTML and CSS is pretty easy to read and understand if you do it right.

Right way:

```
<div class="done_right"> 
   <ul>
       <li>
           <p>
              "This is the right way!"
           </p>
       </li><!---End of li--->
   </ul><!---End of ul--->
</div> <!---End of done_right--->
```

This is a bit of an over-exaggerated example, but indenting and commenting where an element ends can be very helpful, especially when handling long lines of code.

For the CSS part i would suggest to break different elements into different sections.

Say for example you have to pages - called "index" and "contact".

I would put all the code for each page in it's own "section". Like this:

```
/*******Index Page******/
.index_header{
   background-color: red;
 }

/*******Contact Page******/
.contact_header{
   background-color: green;
 }
```

These are just simple tips on how to improve your codes readability.

Comment: Thanks, with that in mind, I am good to go. Thanks.

Comment: And what about the documentation of the whole webpage or template in a word document? How do you go about that just in case clients ask for it?

Comment: Depends on the project. I would recommend writing a read me text, explaining different elements and their css classes. I wouldn't worry about other developers if your "only" using html and css. These are pretty basic. What would matter for other developers is if you would use a css framework like bootstrap. When you should put a link in the read me file to the framework documentation. Same goes for any js or jquery plugins you might use. If you find my answer good enough, please mark it as correct or mark it as useful.

Comment: Can you show me how if it's a css framework like bootstrap

Comment: Bootstrap is a collection of css classes and some javascript components. It's particularly useful when building responsive websites. Their documentation contain all you need to know http://getbootstrap.com/. I personally use it on every project.

Comment: Thanks so much, life will now move even smoother.